# Error in browserbox javascript email code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, browser

I tried using emailjs browserbox to connect to an imap server but the sample script with the correct port and host and username and password just throws out errors and doesn't work in a client-side html file?

https://github.com/whiteout-io/browserbox is a link to the api. What's wrong with how I wrote the code?

```
<html>  
<head>      
<title>Test</title>         
<!-- Required for non-Unicode encodings -->         
<script src="encoding-indexes.js"></script>         
<script src="encoding.js"></script>         
<script src="stringencoding.min.js"></script>       
<script src="browserbox.js"></script>       
<script src="browserbox-imap.js"></script>      
<script>  var client = new BrowserBox('host', port, {
    auth: {
        user: 'testuser',
        pass: 'testpass'
    },
    id: {
        name: 'My Client',
        version: '0.1'
    } });
</script>
    </head>     
     <body>

    </body> 
</html>
```